# How to install Splunk Universal Forward as a service?

Tags: splunk

I need to install Splunk Universal Forwarder in our AWS EC2 instance. I need it to be installed as a service so that it automatically starts when the instance starts. The Splunk Docs do not seem to cover that:

https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Forwarder/8.0.2/Forwarder/Installanixuniversalforwarder#Install_from_a_tar_file

Answer (score 0):

Starting the Splunk Forwarder at boot time is the same process as Splunk Enterprise, which is documented at
https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/ConfigureSplunktostartatboottime

For systemd based OSs, you can follow the instructions from
https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/RunSplunkassystemdservice

Actual process depends on the OS you're running.